# Adding a QComboBox for specific columns for each row PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox

I have a QT Table Widget where I get data from sql, I wanted to put a combo box to the column 4, 5, 6 and 7 (for now let's do it only for the 4th column). I did it but when I execute the the code my QComboBox is shown only in the last row, this because I have a for cycle that inserts rows in the table and I put the self.table.setCellWidget(row, column, combobox) in this loop, so everytime it's executed it moves the combobox to the last row, how can I have a combo box for each row? Here's my code

```
 def datitabella(self):    
    delegate = MyDelegate(self)
    tablerow = 0 
    conteggio = c.execute('SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Viaggi').fetchone()[0]
    combo = QComboBox()
    for p in c.execute("SELECT Customer_code FROM Customers "):
        combo.addItem(str(p))         
    for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM Viaggi "):
        righe = 0 
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setRowCount(conteggio)
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(tablerow, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[0])))
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(tablerow, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[1]))
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(tablerow, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[2]))
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(tablerow, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[3]))
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(tablerow, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[4]))
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(tablerow, 5, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[5]))
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(tablerow, 6, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[6]))
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(tablerow, 7, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[7]))
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setItem(tablerow, 19, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(row[19])))
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setCellWidget(tablerow, 4, combo)
        tablerow+= 1           
    self.tabella_registrazioni.itemChanged.connect(self.changeIcon) 
    self.tabella_registrazioni.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new QComboBox for each row:

```py
def datitabella(self):    
    delegate = MyDelegate(self)
    tablerow = 0
    conteggio = c.execute('SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Viaggi').fetchone()[0]
    items = []
    for p in c.execute("SELECT Customer_code FROM Customers "):
        items.append(p[0])         
    for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM Viaggi "):
        combo = QComboBox()
        combo.addItems(items)
        # ...
        self.tabella_registrazioni.setCellWidget(tablerow, 4, combo)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it worked but now I have 2 other questions,
1) why the items in the combo box are shown like this:
('item1'  ,)
('item 2' ,)
instead of 
item1
item2
2) does this operation slow the entire code? before adding this combo the program was executed in less than 1 second, now I have to wait at least 4-5 second, is this normal?

Comment: @IT-SRL 1. I already fixed it since it is part of the original question, 2. That is another question different from the original question so I will ignore it: 1 question per post.

Comment: @eyellanesc ok thanks, i'll create another question